# The API returns a 403 ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT eventhough I have the scopes enabled for playdeveloperreporting

Tags: android, permissions, google-api-python-client, android-vitals

I'm using google python libraty to request ANR data for my app, script is very simple

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret.
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"

# This access scope grants read-only access to the authenticated user's apps
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'playdeveloperreporting'
API_VERSION = 'v1beta1'
ANR_METHOD_NAME = 'apps/com.my.app/anrRateMetricSet'

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
    scopes=SCOPES)


def get_authenticated_service():
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
    credentials = flow.run_local_server(host='localhost',
                                        port=5000,
                                        authorization_prompt_message='Please visit this URL: {url}',
                                        success_message='The auth flow is complete; you may close this window.',
                                        open_browser=True)
    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)


def getAnrReport():
    report_service = get_authenticated_service()
    vitals = report_service.vitals()
    anr = vitals.anrrate()
    userPerceivedAnrRate7dUserWeighted = anr.get(name=ANR_METHOD_NAME, x__xgafv='2').execute()
    report_service.close()


# ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    getAnrReport()
```

But for some reason I get an error

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: 
HttpError 403 when requesting https://playdeveloperreporting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/apps/com.my.app/anrRateMetricSet?%24.xgafv=2&alt=json 
returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". 
Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'method': 'google.play.developer.reporting.v1beta1.VitalsService.GetAnrRateMetricSet', 'service': 'playdeveloperreporting.googleapis.com'}}]"
```

Documentation https://developers.google.com/play/developer/reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/vitals.anrrate/get
says

> Authorization Scopes Requires the following OAuth scope:
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/playdeveloperreporting

Higher level documentation https://developers.google.com/play/developer/reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/vitals.anrrate says

> Required permissions: to access this resource, the calling user needs
> the View app information (read-only) permission for the app.

I do have that permission and my google user can access app info and ANR rate in Google Play Console. I'm also requesting `playdeveloperreporting` scope as per documentation, but the scope is insufficient for some reason, what am I doing wrong?

Note: scope in my script is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher

Documentation says it should be https://www.googleapis.com/auth/playdeveloperreporting
but such scope cannot be requested due to error:

```
Some requested scopes cannot be shown: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/playdeveloperreporting]
Error 400: invalid_scope
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer in issues of this python project
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/1761

> the API right now only supports access with GCP service accounts

So to work with that API I need a service account, not a human one which requires to authorized through web auth.

The way to use a service account is roughly as follows:

The way to use a service account is roughly as follows:

1. Create a GCP consumer project and get an API key for it
2. Link your GCP consumer project to the Play Console developer account in the API access UI
3. Create a service account (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts), and download the account's key file (the equivalent of its password)
4. "Invite" that service account to be a user of your Play Console developer, and grant at least "read only" access to some or all apps.
5. Exchange the service account key for an OAuth token using a tool such as oauth2l.

Answer (score 0):

We were trying to do the same for a customer so tried different scenarii and we realised that the Service Account does not need to be from a project linked to your Play Console. So just editing @Wackaloon's Answer

1)Create a GCP consumer project and Create a service account (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts), and download the account's key file (the equivalent of its password).

2)"Invite" that service account to be a user of the Play Console developer, and grant Account permissions > "View app information and download bulk reports (read-only)" to access the reports Reviews, Statistics> Installs, Crashes, Ratings, Subscriptions, add "View financial data, orders, and cancellation survey responses" for access to reports Financials> Earnings, Estimated Sales.

When granting only App permission, we were encountering the error `AccessDeniedException: 403 user@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.`